# How to check if an implementation is available for a certain generic interface?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, system.reflection

If I have an interface 
`IEqualityCustomComparer<in T, in TClient>`, 
how do I find out if this interface has been implemented by a particular class like 
`public class ParticipantComparer : IEqualityCustomComparer<Participant, ParticipantEntity> { ... }`.

All I know is T is of type Participant, and TClient is of type ParticipantEntity. I want to check if the interface for these types have been implemented, and execute a particular snippet of code if that's true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isImplementationOf =
    typeof(IEqualityCustomComparer<,>)
        .MakeGenericType(new []
        {
            typeof(Participant),
            typeof(ParticipantEntity),
        })
        .IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ParticipantComparer));
```

This code would be used with variables in the array, not `typeof` operators, as the following would be better if the types are known at compile-time.

```
var isImplementationOf =
    typeof(IEqualityCustomComparer<Participant, ParticipantEntity>)
        .IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ParticipantComparer));
```

Comment: Creating a type to compare a type is very expensive.

Comment: @DaveHaney - What do you mean by expensive?

Comment: @DaveHaney - Expensive only if the types (T,V) within <T,V> are of different value types which does not exists in the executing code. if T,V are of reference types then no impact as the T,V use the existing in memory instance of the generic type and it is just the references which will get replaced. A detailed answer is at source. Source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4a6ta2h.aspx

Comment: @DaveHaney - I did a +1 for your comment as it can be a good question, not because this answer was wrong, though I have provided a simplified answer.

Comment: @KajalSinha the problem with this answer is twofold in my opinion. 1 is that it created a type instance per comparison which will allocate memory and also have to be garbage collected. 2 is that I feel that the OP wants to know how to check for the generic interface without knowledge of the particular type parameters. In this answer `Participant` and `ParticipantEntity` must be known at compile time.

Comment: @DaveHaney - Thanks but it won't create a new type per instance, the reason is generics work differently for Reference types (if Participant and ParticipantEntity are of reference types and I hope they are). The msdn link I shared is quite descriptive.

Comment: As per question "All I know is T is of type Participant, and TClient is of type ParticipantEntity" So both types are known at compile time.

Comment: What I meant by "All i knoiw is..." is that I do not have an instance of the comparer (e.g ParticipantComparer).
So, first I need to check if there is a class that implements IEqualityCustomComparer<T, TClient> for that particular T, TClient. If so I need to create a new instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following, it just works!

```
  ParticipantComparer theObject = new ParticipantComparer();

  if (typeof(IEqualityCustomComparer<Participant, ParticipantEntity>).IsInstanceOfType(theObject))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Assignable");
            }
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to know how to do this without regard for the particular types instantiated.

Comment: OP did mention he/she knows that the types are Participant and ParticipantEntity.

Comment: Ahh, you are correct! Does your answer account for covariance and contravariance correctly though? What if it is `IEqualityCustomComparer<DerivedParticipant, DerivedParticipantEntity>`?

Answer (score -1):

To the best of my knowledge this can only be done with reflection. This is because the generic type implementation is not created until runtime and your code can't possible know what it will be at compile time. So, reflection saves the day:

```
bool result = type.GetInterfaces()
    .Any(i => i.IsGenericType 
        && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEqualityCustomComparer<,>));
```

Your best bet (to avoid the reflection performance penalties) is probably a marker interface... Have `IEqualityCustomComparer<,>` implement `IEqualityCustomComparer` which does nothing and then do a soft `as` or `is` check:

```
if (customClass is IEqualityCustomComparer)
...
```

Comment: dear down voter, if you dont like the comment about "runtime" then explain so. Generally when down voting please say why.